# Bus waiting time

Tags: probability

Agneta takes the bus to school every morning. The buses goes 5 times every hour, but since Agneta has neither time table or a watch, she consider her waiting time as random. What is the probability that her shortest waiting time during a 5 day period is no more than 2.4 minutes.

I understand that Agneta's waiting time is a random variable, but I don't understand what distribution the random variable should have. If I knew the probability density function, then I would calculate the probability as

$$
P(\zeta < 2.4) = \int_0^{2.4} f_{\zeta}(x)dx
$$

where

$$
\zeta \in \xi_1 + \xi_2 + \xi_3 + \xi_4 + \xi_5 
$$

where $\xi_1,\xi_2,...,\xi_5$ are the probabilities for each day. Could it be done like this, or is their an easier way of doing this that I am totally missing?

Comment: Its a scaled beta distribution. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Order_statistics_sampled_from_a_uniform_distribution

Comment: I would think it natural to assume that the busses leave at _uniform intervals_ five times every hour, which means that the waiting time for any specific day is uniform on $[0, 12]$.

Comment: @Arthur So, you mean that

$$
\begin{cases}
f(t)  = \frac{1}{5}, \ \ 0 < t < 12 \\
0, \ \ annars
\end{cases}
$$

or what?

Comment: That is not a probaility distribution function, it doesn't integrate to 1. The $\frac15$ must be replaced with $\frac1{12}$.  But the remainder of your approach is  a mystery to me , because summing up the probabilities makes no sense.
Better think about what the probability is for any random day to have a waiting time of at least 2.4 min and try to go from there.

Comment: My bad, of course it should be

$$
f(t) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{12}, \ \ 0 < t < 12 \\
0, \ \ otherwise
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 2):

It's safe to assume from common sense that bus arrivals distributed uniformly throughout the hour and not random. That means the interval between two busses is 12 minutes, and Agneta comes at a random point in that interval. So the distribution of her waiting time is uniform $t\sim U_{[0,12]}$. The probability that minimum is less that 2.4 is
$$
P(\min t_i<2.4) = 1-P(\min t_i >2.4) = 1-\prod P(t_i>2.4)=1-\left(\frac{12-2.4}{12}\right)^5=0.67
$$

If the busses are random and their timetable works like [Poisson proceess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process), then the distribution of waiting time would be exponential.